# Get the Height of a child div data attribute and then set the Height of the Parent

Tags: jquery, css, height

The html looks like this.

```
  <div id="carousel4up"> 
       <div class="owl-carousel" data-composer='carousel4up' data-config='{
       "height" : 350, "other": false }'
        ...
        </div>
  </div>
```

The hight is set from a data-config file and it could change. I want to set `id="carousel4up"` height based on the value  of `class="owl-carousel"` data configs key value pair of height.

Here is my start js

```
       var owlHeight = $(".owl-carousel").attr(data-config); 
       $("#carousel4up").height(owlHeight);
```

I dont know how to through the array and locate the get the value of the height though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem, you need to have single quotes:

```
data-config='{"height" : 350, "other": false }';
```

To make the attribute into a JS array, do it like:

```
    var owlHeight = $.parseJSON($(".owl-carousel").attr('data-config'));
    //or the non-jQuery version JSON.parse($(".owl-carousel").attr('data-config'));
```

Then call it like:

```
$("#carousel4up").height(owlHeight['height']);
```

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cgda0k0x/1/)

Comment: thnks seems to work in my console. Will test in app and confirm. I don't understand why the json would have to be in single quotes though

Comment: @nolawipetros it does not have to be, how you had it would probably have messed up your html, and if it did work, would most likely have been buggy

Comment: @nolawipetros actually, i you either have to use single quotes, or escape all the double quotes. single quotes are easier

Answer (score 1):

If as you provided data is in [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format then you could do this:

```js
// Use attr if you expect the data-config value to change in javascript
// Otherwise use .data()
var config = $("#carousel4up .owl-carousel").attr("data-config");
// JSON.parse converts json string to javascript object
var height = JSON.parse(config).height;

$("#carousel4up").css("height", height + "px");
```

```css
#carousel4up {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="carousel4up"> 
  <div class="owl-carousel" data-composer="carousel4up" data-config='{"height" : 350, "other": false }'>  
    I am big, yay!
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 var owlHeight = $(".owl-carousel").attr(data-config);
```

to this

```
 var owlHeight = $(".owl-carousel").data('config'); 
 //or .attr('data-config');
```